# XOM convert XML (SVG) into XSL stylesheet

Tags: xml, xslt, xom

I'm trying to turn an SVG file into an XSL stylesheet as per this article:http://www.linuxjournal.com/article/9283?page=0,0

I've tried to simply construct a new document with the svg data inserted between the XSL related elements however when I execute the method containing this code:

```
        Document input=builder.build(sourcefile);
        Element styletags=new Element("xsl:stylesheet",
                                      "http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform");
        styletags.appendChild(new Element("xsl:template%20match=\"/\""));
        styletags.appendChild(input);
        Document result=new Document(styletags);
```

I get the following exception:

> nu.xom.NamespaceConflictException: Prefixed elements must have namespace URIs.

If I try with the following code

`Element xsl=new Element("template%20match=\"/\"");
            xsl.addNamespaceDeclaration("xsl","http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform");
            Element styletags=new Element("stylesheet");
            styletags.addNamespaceDeclaration("xsl","http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform");
            styletags.appendChild(xsl);
            styletags.appendChild(input);`

I get

> nu.xom.IllegalNameException: 0x25 is not a legal NCName character

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 0):

You can’t do this:

```
new Element("xsl:template%20match=\"/\"")
```

You have to define the name (`xsl:template`) when you create the element and then add the attribute (`match=""`). Like this:

```
Element template = new Element("xsl:template", "http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform");
template.addAttribute(new Attribute("match", ""));
```